# How to check a String (E.G. "ababac") for the times any given Character appears more than once? (E.G. a=3, b=2)

Tags: python, python-3.x

what i'm finding hard is that you can't nest "i for i in [list]" inside Boolean logic checks, and not wanting to list all 26 characters

Comment: [`collections.Counter("ababac")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting Letter Frequency in a String (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985203/counting-letter-frequency-in-a-string-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `"aabc".count('a')` to give you the amount of times `a` appears in `aabc`, for example. In this example, it gives `2`.

Building on from this, you could implement some simple code to check how many times every letter of the alphabet occurs like so:

```
import string

s = 'ababac'

for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print("%s appears %s times" % (letter, s.count(letter)))
```

Which produces the output:

```
a appears 3 times
b appears 2 times
c appears 1 times
d appears 0 times
e appears 0 times
f appears 0 times
g appears 0 times
...
```

NB: you don't have to list all 26 characters in the alphabet because `string.ascii_lowercase` has that for you. Note there is also `string.ascii_uppercase` and so on. More information: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

For more information about `str.count(sub[, start[, end]])`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count

Also `collections.Counter` can create a dictionary for all the letters in the string. Using this, you could rewrite the above code like so:

```
import string
from collections import Counter

counts=Counter('ababac')
# counts = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}

for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
    if letter in counts:
        print("%s appears %s times" % (letter, counts[letter]))
    else:
        print("%s doesn't appear" % letter)
```

Output:

```
a appears 3 times
b appears 2 times
c appears 1 times
d doesn't appear
e doesn't appear
f doesn't appear
g doesn't appear
...
```

---

Edit NB:

```
print("%s appears %s times" % (letter, s.count(letter)))
```

can also be written as:

```
print("{} appears {} times".format(letter, s.count(letter)))
```

using the newer `str.format` interface. More information: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format.

Comment: thanks! this solves my problem, but I don't get how:

 `("%s appears %s times" % (letter, s.count(letter)))`

works. where can I check about this specific string usage?

Comment: It's called string formatting. Some more information: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting. There are actually a newer and better ways to do this too nowadays, more information about another way: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Answer (score 0):

using `defualtdict` you can do this way .

```
from collections import defaultdict
def fun():
    return 0

dic=defaultdict(fun)

string ='ababa'

for i in string:
    dic[i]+=1

for i in dic:
    print(i,dic[i])
```

output:

```
 a 3 
 b 2
```

Comment: rather than doing `defaultdict(fun)` you could use a lambda method like so `defaultdict(lambda: 0)`, which means you don't need to define `fun`

Comment: @AbhinavBhandari i know, my main motive is to let the OP  to understand the code and solve it in future and also no use of any library

Answer (score 0):

You can get the each available characters count in a given string using below code

```
def count_dict(mystring):
    d = {}
# count occurances of character
    for w in mystring: 
        d[w] = mystring.count(w)
# print the result
    for k in sorted(d):
        print (k + ': ' + str(d[k]))

mystring='qwertyqweryyyy'
count_dict(mystring)
```

You can find the live demo [**here**](https://rextester.com/EBL1413)

Comment: Suraj, you're already linking to the demo in your answer, there is no need to attempt to edit the link into prashant's answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21843571