# how to use python to find the first not repeating character?

Tags: python, list

I am solving a problem: Given a string s consisting of small English letters, find and return the first instance of a non-repeating character in it. If there is no such character, return '_'.

For example: s = "abacabad", the output should be firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s) = 'c'.

I wrote a simple code, it got through all the test, but when I submit it, it reports error, anyone know what's wrong with my code? Thank you!

```
def firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s):   
    for i in list(s):
        if list(s).count(i) == 1:
            return i
    return '_'
```

Comment: *What* error...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting Letter Frequency in a String (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985203/counting-letter-frequency-in-a-string-python)

Comment: Tests passed: 15/19. Execution time limit exceeded on test 16: Program exceeded the execution time limit. Make sure that it completes execution in a few seconds for any possible input.

Comment: I am practice on a website, maybe because my code was too slow? There is better code?

Comment: @Qing according to the error ` Execution time limit exceeded` your code is slower than what the test demands

Comment: Yeah I realized that. I need to work on that :/ Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could be a performance issue as your repeated `count` (and unnecessary list conversions) calls make this approach quadratic. You should aim for a linear solution:

```
from collections import Counter

def firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s):   
    c = Counter(s)
    for i in s:
        if c[i] == 1:
            return i
    return '_'
```

You can also use `next` with a generator and a default value:

```
def firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s):   
    c = Counter(s)
    return next((i for i in s if c[i] == 1), '_')
```

If you can only use built-ins, just make your own counter (or any other data structure that allows you to identify duplicates)

```
def firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s):   
    c = {}
    for i in s:
        c[i] = c.get(i, 0) + 1
    return next((i for i in s if c[i] == 1), '_')
```

Comment: I am practicing online on a website, it doesn't allow me to import anything... and the error was "Tests passed: 15/19. Execution time limit exceeded on test 16: Program exceeded the execution time limit. Make sure that it completes execution in a few seconds for any possible input." So I am wondering is it because my code was too slow?

Comment: @Qing I added a linear approach using only built-ins. And yes, for large input data (e.g. strings with 10^5 chars), your solution will become very slow.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I don't understand why my code was wrong?

Comment: Not wrong, but slow because of the (underlying) nested loop algorithm: "for each char in string -> count that char in the string". The linear approaches I suggest count all chars in a single iteration and then use that information in a second iteration.

Comment: Oh that make sense. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The task at hand is to find first non repeating character from a given string e.g. s = 'aabsacbhsba'

```py
def solution(s):
    # This will take each character from the given string s one at a time 
    for i in s: 
        if s.index(i) == s.rindex(i): # rindex() returns last index of i in s 
            return i  
    return  '_'
```

Here `s.rindex(i)` method finds the last occurrence of the specified value [value at i in s in our case] we are comparing it with current index `s.index(i)`, if they return the same value we found the first occurance of specified value which is not repeated

You can find definition and usage of `rindex()` at : [W3School rindex()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_rindex.asp)

Comment: I think you can make this faster, but I suppose this will work if it's just lowercase.

Comment: Since the question says that string s consists of lowercase characters it should give correct answer all the times. In case we are using this to find first occurrence of a non-repeating character which includes both upper and lower case characters, we can just use ``s.lower()`` to convert the given string to lowercase and then we can proceed to find our character.